# Integral value of z

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given two rationals $x,y \in \mathbb Q$. If we have $x^2 + y^2 = z$  , then what all integral values can $z$ take ?

Answer (score 5):

The Diophantine equation $x^2+y^2=z$ has a solution in integers if and only if every prime $p\equiv 3(4)$ of the prime decomposition of $z$ arises with **even** exponent, i.e., $z=1,2,4,5,8,9,10,13,16,...$, see Sloane $A001481$ integer sequences. For rational solutions, multiply by common denominator, and 
then argue that  if an integer $n$ is the sum of two squares of rationals then it’s also the sum of two squares of integers.

Edit: the question changes more quickly than I can answer. For real numbers every non-negative integer $z$ can arise. Take $x=0$ and $y=\sqrt{z}$. The original question asked for *integer* solutions. I thank tohecz for helping me here.

Comment: Dietrich, if you checked the edit history, you would see that ulead86 made an invalid edit, changing _rationals_ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: However, he asks for $x,y\in\mathbb Q$ and $x^2+y^2\in\mathbb Z$. You might want to explain in detail that this is the same as $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ and $x^2+y^2\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Well, you just got very close to getting a downvote from me. It's true that it's the same, however after dividing by $z$ you get $x^2/z+y^2/z=1$ or (after substitution) $zx^2+zy^2=1$. Now, you have to say that $z$ divides $1$ therefore $z=\pm1$ and we can ignore it. I don't think it's a good idea to omit such details, they seem trivial to us maybe, but probably are not trivial to OP. Still, they are quite crucial in understanding the ideas behind.

Comment: Well, your solution works for the current version of the question (which is hopefully the one OP wanted to ask). You just might want to explain that $x,y$ need to be integers (which you explained in the comments I think). Sorry, I seem to be getting lost in it myself  :-/

Comment: @DietrichBrude the original question was of rational number. I haven't understood your solution clear . Can you please explain it clearly ?

Comment: Then I misread it, I am sorry. I saw "integer" solution, then "rational", and after that it was **rational**, in boldface. Here is a link with more details:  cims.nyu.edu/~bakker/math248/quadforms.pdf‎